# Yii Update CGridView based on dropdown select

Tags: php, ajax, yii

**FOUND A SOLUTION CHECK END OF THIS POST**

I'm been working on this for 4 weeks and I haven't made any headway. I have found tons of similar examples online and yet everything I tried I couldn't get to work. So I had to burden the community with another of my questions.

I have a model/table called tbl_symptoms/Symptoms which has 7 columns/attributes:
id, symptomCode,  title, shortTitle, inclusions, exclusions, symptomCategory.

I use a dropdown select (which gets populated from a table on the server that just has the symptom categories in one column).

While I can get the gridview to populate with ALL the symptoms, I can't get it to only populate with the same category symptoms as the dropdown.

This is the last solution I tried out (right now it's not even rendering the gridview, but even when it did I had other problems, so I'm just posting the code so you guys have a point of reference about potential solutions):

**Symptoms.php search function:**

```
public function search()
{
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;


    $criteria->compare('symptomCategory',$this->symptomCategory,true);


    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}
```

**SiteController.php functions I'm using:**

```
//returns symptom categories that the user can choose to pick a symptom
public static function getSymptomCategories()
{
    return CHtml::listData(Yii::app()->db->createCommand()->select('category')->from('tbl_symptomcategory')->queryAll(), 'category', 'category');
}

public function actionLoadSymptoms()
{
    $symptomsModel = new Symptoms;

    if (isset($_POST)){
        $symptomsModel->attributes = $_POST;
        $dataProvider = $symptomsModel->search();
        $this->renderPartial('_searchSymptomsView', array('dataProvider' => $dataProvider));
    }
}
```

**view file _seachSymptomsView:**

```
    <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'searchSymptomsGrid',
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'columns'=>array(
        'symptomCode',
        'title',
        'inclusions',
        'exclusions',
        'symptomCategory',
        )
        ));
        ?>
```

**search.php functions:**

```
<!-- Select symptom category dropdown menu -->
<div class="search-form">
        <?php 
            echo $form->labelEx($model, 'symptomCategory'); 
            echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'symptomCategory', 
                    $this->getSymptomCategories(),
                    array( 'id'=>'symptomSelectDropdown',
                           'ajax'=>array('type'=>'POST',
                                        'url'=>CController::createUrl('SiteController/loadSymptoms'),
                                        'replace'=>'#symptomSelectDiv'
                            )));

           ?>

           <!-- select symptom -->
<div class="row" id="symptomSelectDiv">

</div>
```

This code is based on a similar question asked here but I couldn't get it to work like everything else I've tried.
Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

**SOLUTION I CAME UP WITH** (for future reference)

Symptoms model search function: pretty much the default constructed function, but I commented out everything except the symptomCategory which is what I wanted to base my search on.

search view file: (revelant stuff)

```
   Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('search', "
        $('#symptomSelectDiv').hide();
        $('#categorySelectDropDown').change(function(){
            $('#symptomSelectDiv').show();
            $('#symptoms-grid').yiiGridView('update', {
                data: $(this).serialize()
            });
            return false;
        });
 "); 
    ?>
     <h1>Welcome to the search for symptoms page </h1>

    <div class="form">
    <?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
'id'=>'search-form',
'enableClientValidation'=>true,
'clientOptions'=>array(
    'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
),
    )); ?>



 <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>
<!-- Select symptom category dropdown menu -->
<div class="search-form">
        <?php        $this->renderPartial('_searchCategory',array('model'=>$model)); ?>
</div>


           <!-- select symptom -->
<div class="row" id="symptomSelectDiv" >
    <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
            'id'=>'symptoms-grid',
            'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
            'columns'=>array(
                'symptomCode',
                'title',
                'inclusions',
                'exclusions',
                'symptomCategory',

            ),
    )); ?>
</div>



<div class="row buttons">
    <?php  echo CHtml::submitButton('Search');  ?>
</div>



   <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

_searchCategory.php view:

```
  <php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
'action'=>Yii::app()->createUrl($this->route),
'method'=>'get', 
  )); ?>
<!-- form is automatically submitted when dropdown selection changes -->
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->label($model,'symptomCategory'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'symptomCategory',
                                            $this->getSymptomCategories(),
                                            array('submit'=>'',
                                                  'id'=>'categorySelectDropDown',
                                                  'prompt'=>"Select Symptom Category")); ?>

</div>


   <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution you found, breaks MVC structure. By the way(skipping that solution), you did not use a `filter` in your `gridView`.

By default `CGridView` uses text input at header to perform filtering. If you want to use a `dropDown` you must change your column's filter like below:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'searchSymptomsGrid',
'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
'columns'=>array(
    'symptomCode',
    'title',
    'inclusions',
    'exclusions',
    array(
         'name'=>'symptomCategory',
         'type' => 'raw',
         'filter' => array('KEY'=>'VALUE','KEY1'=>'VALUE1'), //Note 1
         'value'=>'$data->symptomCategory' //Note 2
    )
    )
    ));
```

**Note 1 in comments**

This array will be shown in a `dropdown` format in `symptomCategory` column header. You can replace it with your own array (with specific keys and values )

**Note 2 in comments**

It shows the value of `symptomCategory` column. You can change it with your own (for example format it or something else)

**Yii** has a powerful and comprehensive document. It is recommended to take a look at CGridView to know more about it. If you take a look, you will definitely be able to perform more customization.

[CGridView Documents](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView)

Comment: But doesn't this just create a drop down inside the grid view? I wanted the drop down to be separate from the grid view. And thank you for your answer, I will take some time tomorrow to read more about filters

Comment: You're welcome dear, But I don't get what you mean by separate from GridView.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I found out the solution I was looking for by myself but I realized I was making a major mistake with the way I populated the dropdown which I fixed thanks to your "Note 1", so thank you :).

Comment: Ali this is what I had in mind https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2935/14225357064_5efd60b65d_o.jpg

Comment: You're welcome dear. It was my misunderstand. By the way, I'm glad to hear you solved your problem. Good luck